# Getting data from a service Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray

am new to iOS, Getting issue with displaying data from below service data

```
[{
    "Name": Rahul,
    "FatherName": Ravinder,
    "Designation": Engineering,
    "Profession": Software Eng,
    "Height": "5 ft 3 in",
    "Weight": "134.5 lbs"
}]
```

below is the code what i have tried. Please help me to find the issue. Thanks In Advance.

```
 NameDetails.m
---------------

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self callService:[appDelegate.signUpdata objectForKey:@"id"]];
}

-(void)callService:(NSString *)userid
{
    [Utility showIndicator:nil view1:self.view];
    JsonServicePostData = [[JsonServiceCls alloc] init];
    JsonServicePostData.delegate = self;
    [JsonServicePostData Getdata:userid];
}

-(void)DidFinishWebServicesPostData
{
    [Utility hideIndicator];

        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        _txtName.text=[dict objectForKey:@"Name"];
        _txtFName.text=[dict objectForKey:@"FatherName"];
        _txtDesg.text=[dict objectForKey:@"Designation"];
        _txtprof.text=[dict objectForKey:@"Profession"];
        _txtHeight.text=[dict objectForKey:@"Height"];
        _txtWeight.text=[dict objectForKey:@"Weight"];

    }

}
```

Comment: how "dict" is getting data from api?. its just initialize here, it does not have any data in it. "DidFinishWebServicesPostData" suppose to return a json from API here.

Answer (score 1):

```
+(void)makeHttpGETresponceParsingwithSerVer:(NSString *)strServer withCallBack:(void(^)(NSDictionary *dicArr,NSError *error))handler
{

NSURL *urlServer = [NSURL URLWithString:strServer];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlServer];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];


            handler(res,error);


    }];

    [postDataTask resume];
}
then call your method In viewDidLoad...

[RestClient makeHttpGETresponceParsingwithSerVer:@"YOUR_URL" withCallBack:^(NSDictionary *responceDic, NSError *error) {

    _txtName.text   =[responceDic objectForKey:@"Name"];
    _txtFName.text  =[responceDic objectForKey:@"FatherName"];
    _txtDesg.text   =[responceDic objectForKey:@"Designation"];
    _txtprof.text   =[responceDic objectForKey:@"Profession"];
    _txtHeight.text =[responceDic objectForKey:@"Height"];
    _txtWeight.text =[responceDic objectForKey:@"Weight"];

}];
```

// RestClient is the class name as it is a class method, You can use instance method.

Answer (score 0):

Hi The better approach is for this kind of API call activity you have to go with AFNetworking - https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Its Pretty simple and more powerful. Once you get the json response you have to go for Model Approach.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NameDetails : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * designation;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * fatherName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * height;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * profession;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * weight;

-(instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;

-(NSDictionary *)toDictionary;
@end

#import "RootClass.h"

NSString *const kRootClassDesignation = @"Designation";
NSString *const kRootClassFatherName = @"FatherName";
NSString *const kRootClassHeight = @"Height";
NSString *const kRootClassName = @"Name";
NSString *const kRootClassProfession = @"Profession";
NSString *const kRootClassWeight = @"Weight";

@interface RootClass ()
@end
@implementation RootClass




/**
 * Instantiate the instance using the passed dictionary values to set the properties values
 */

-(instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    self = [super init];
    if(![dictionary[kRootClassDesignation] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
        self.designation = dictionary[kRootClassDesignation];
    }   
    if(![dictionary[kRootClassFatherName] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
        self.fatherName = dictionary[kRootClassFatherName];
    }   
    if(![dictionary[kRootClassHeight] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
        self.height = dictionary[kRootClassHeight];
    }   
    if(![dictionary[kRootClassName] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
        self.name = dictionary[kRootClassName];
    }   
    if(![dictionary[kRootClassProfession] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
        self.profession = dictionary[kRootClassProfession];
    }   
    if(![dictionary[kRootClassWeight] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
        self.weight = dictionary[kRootClassWeight];
    }   
    return self;
}


/**
 * Returns all the available property values in the form of NSDictionary object where the key is the approperiate json key and the value is the value of the corresponding property
 */
-(NSDictionary *)toDictionary
{
    NSMutableDictionary * dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    if(self.designation != nil){
        dictionary[kRootClassDesignation] = self.designation;
    }
    if(self.fatherName != nil){
        dictionary[kRootClassFatherName] = self.fatherName;
    }
    if(self.height != nil){
        dictionary[kRootClassHeight] = self.height;
    }
    if(self.name != nil){
        dictionary[kRootClassName] = self.name;
    }
    if(self.profession != nil){
        dictionary[kRootClassProfession] = self.profession;
    }
    if(self.weight != nil){
        dictionary[kRootClassWeight] = self.weight;
    }
    return dictionary;

}
```

The above one is Model Class.

Your JSON look like a array. So you need to iterate the Dictionary values on it. Other than that you may pass it directly.

Now in your ViewController class initiate the mutable array

and pass the response like

```
NSArray *arrayData = ResponseFromAFNETWORKING

    for (NSDictionary *data in arrayData) {
        NameDetails *modelFeed = [[NameDetails alloc] initFromDictinary:data]
       [self.YourMutableDictionary addObject:modelFeed]

    }
self.updateDisplay:self.YourMutableDictionary[0] // If not array No iteration, you can prepare the model and pass it directly
----------------------------------------
- (void)updateDisplay:(NameDetails *)feed {
    _txtName.text   =feed.Name;
    _txtFName.text  =feed.FatherName;
    _txtDesg.text   =feed.Designation;
    _txtprof.text   =feed.Profession;
    _txtHeight.text =feed.Height;
    _txtWeight.text =feed.Weight;

}
```

Hope this will help. This is a robust and elastic approach, thread safe mechanism too